# Fittext.js in a list

Tags: jquery, html, css, fittextjs

I am creating a responsive design and I keep on struggling with one issue: I have a vertical menu for which I use a html list. I want to have the font-size to be adjusted to the width available. For that I use fittext.js which is awesome, but I can't get my vertical list working, I get a list who goes diagonal, and not from up to down like it should.

html:

```
<div class="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="”#”">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="”#”">The Next Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="”#”">Another Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="”#”">Last Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div ul li a {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

My full code if you want fast testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>FitText</title>

    <style type="text/css">
div ul li a {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
    </style>
    <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div class="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="”#”">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="”#”">The Next Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="”#”">Another Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="”#”">Last Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.fittext.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".main-nav ul li a").fitText();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Fittext can you find here: https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wannabe_rockgod suggested, the floated `a` elements were causing the problem but you have to change the jQuery selector too.

Here's a [working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rCfmz).

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I want this menu to be vertical. I have a horizontal menu (which works), and the submenus are on the left in a vertical menu. Deleting the float is bringing it to work in your codepen exampe, so I guess the jquery selector was part of the problem, but I can't get it working in my site. I search a little bit further

Comment: It works like a charm now! Got it working ;-) Thanks a lot!!! Your example works perfect! I had another small typing error in the real file, but now it works perfect :-)

Answer (score 0):

Floating the a tags are probably what's causing the diagonal weirdness. Wouldn't this work?

```
div ul li a {
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The list is shown correctly then but fittext doesn't do his job then. The font-size starts smaller and it only goes smaller, even when you enlarge the screen width.

Comment: @Robin have updated my answer to continue targeting the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use min/max font-size and I think setting the parent with would be better here as we are resizing the inner element 'a' based on the parent 'li' width

CSS

```
.main-nav li {
    width: 25%;
}

.main-nav li a {
    display: block;
}
```

JS

```
$('.main-nav li a').fitText(.5, { minFontSize: '16px', maxFontSize: '32px' });
```